# Can I update a message field from enum to string, and keep its name?

Tags: protocol-buffers

## The Code

Consider the following protobuf message declaration:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

enum Airport {
    TLV = 0;
    JFK = 1;
    ...
}

message Flight {
    ...
    Airport origin_airport = 11;
    ...
}
```

## The Problem

Due to some business requirements, we have to set the `Airport` to be a free string rather than choosing from a closed enumerated list. I know that I can add and remove fields at will, as long as I don't reuse the same number. However, I'm not sure if I can use the same name, a-la:

```
message Flight {
    ...
    reserved 11;                    // The old enum field number
    string origin_airport = 18;     // Unused so far
    ...
}
```

## My Question

**Upon updaing a protobuf3 field type, can the field name be preserved, as long as its number changes?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't using the JSON variant, then names aren't used at all in the payload, so yes *technically* it is perfectly legal to reuse names; however: this might lead to unnecessary problems with existing code - depending on existing code and language / framework specific rules, and could cause confusion. Since that is avoidable, I would advocate using a name like `origin_airport_code`, or similar.

(The point I'm making here: any code that used the old field probably needs attention; I can see some scenarios where the existing code might **still compile** after the change, but mean something different, and therefore introduce a bug that would have been avoided if you'd changed the name and forced every usage to be visited)

Comment: Good points! I'm starting to think that I'm going to use Hungarian notation to avoid this :-)